# Common method for several generic classes to use

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have several classes that implement IMyInterface.  The interface contains a method called Delete, so all classes define their own Delete method.

I also have a lot of spots in my code where I’m calling MyClass1.Delete(myClass1Id) or MyClass2.Delete(myClass2Id), etc.

I’m trying to define a generic, common method that takes a generic class parameter and a string for the Id.

I’m guessing it would look something like this, but I can’t find any relevant documentation on using generic classes in this fashion:

```
public static void DeleteGeneric<TMyClass>(string myId)
{
    //call the relevant Delete method for the TMyClass class
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Can you give a more full example of the code you're trying to improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use generics here at all; just accept an instance of the interface:

```
public static void DeleteGeneric(IMyInterface deletable, string myId)
{
    deletable.Delete(myId);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the type parameter

Answer (score 1):

I think you want code like this:

```
public static void DeleteGeneric<TMyClass>(TMyClass myId) where TMyClass : IMyInterface
{
    myId.Delete();
}
```

That says that TMyClass has to implement the IMyInterface interface and the parameter passed is of whatever type TMyClass is.

It might be simpler without generics

```
public static void DeleteGeneric(IMyInterface myId)
{
    myId.Delete();
}
```

Disclaimer, I typed this code into the browser so there maybe syntax errors.